# python list max - returning every time different result

Tags: python, django, list

I have this queries:

```
res = []
obj1= MyModel1.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
obj2= MyModel2.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
res.extend(x for x in (obj1, obj2))
max_res = max(res)
```

but it is giving me everytime different results - meaning, one time one object from MyModel1, another time another object from MyModel2. My Wish is to get the latest object amon these 2 Models.

I tried with:

```
max_res = max(res, key=lambda r: r.id)
```

but it is saying: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Is the repeated assignment to `obj1` intentional?

Comment: @kviiri oh sorry, my typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ordered_by` returns a queryset, you need to get the *object* inside this queryset. I know you are doing slicing, but your slicing will also return a queryset, not an object.

If you want to find the latest object, in your case it means the one with the highest id, you need the following query:

```
obj1 = MyModel1.objects.latest('id')
obj2 = MyModel1.objects.latest('id')

max([obj1,obj2], key=lambda x: x.id)
```